# How to host a web service so other clients connected to same network can access

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, web, hosting

I am hosting web service in a one machine using Visual studio 2008. I tried accessing the web service from a web site i created in the same solution and it was successfully called. Now i want to access the web service from a remote client.

I initially developed the web service to used in an android application. As you can see if I wan to access the web service I will have to host is with a static IP. So at least to test the application *i want access the web service from the android mobile by connecting both server and android mobile to one wifi network*. For the initial test I connected two laptops(one is server) to the wifi router. And i pingd the server from the client machine and it got successfully pingd. But when i try to access the web service with given port from the browser it wont allow me to connect. I tried `http://localhost:26796/` by replacing the localhost with ip of the server and also i tried making a small web site(asp) and try to access it from the client via IP. Both did not work. I have searched here and on web could not find a proper answer. for,

1. how to host a webservice so other clients in the same network can access..?
2. can it be fulfilled with VSD server..?
3. is it compulsory to use iis..?
4. How should i achieve this..?

Comment: This is an overly broad question. It doesn't matter where or what from you're trying to access the web service (be it Android or whatever), rather you should try reading through the copious amount of literature out there regarding .NET web services and try to work your way through examples. Then you can come back and ask specific questions about specific problems you encounter.

Comment: I did. I put this much of word to convey my idea. I can access my web service locally without any issue. I want to access it from another client connected to same network. With the normal debugging mode if VSD server it is not possible to access the web service. Went through lots of literature no one has given a proper answer other than hosting it with a static ip or using iis. Is there alternative.. If not what is the available solutions..?

Comment: Is there a firewall or proxy maybe that is preventing the connection from succeeding? What exceptions are you getting? You simply are not providing enough information to even make an educated guess.

Comment: Publish the web service to your local machine's IIS as an Application. Then you can access the site from anywhere in your network. Running it directly from VS means it's hosted inside VS's ASP.NET Development Server (which, by default is only accessible locally). You can try opening up the port specified in the ASP.NET development server that starts up on your machine's local firewall, then you can access the debug instance being hosted.

Comment: I hosted it to IIS. Now it can be accessed via network clients. Could not find another way. Thanks all for all the replies

Comment: What kind of web service are you looking to do? SOAP? REST? All of technologies have SOAP proxy generators. You can also create a WCF service which output the data as xml or json

Comment: ^^ Might help to know what kind of service this is? Because, as an example, if it is a WCF service, we haven't even discussed endpoint config yet.

Comment: @tobias86 : Why don't you post as answer? Will help the community to find answers, with similar problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** Moved from comments to answer as per user suggestion.

Publish the web service to your local machine's IIS as an Application. Then you can access the site from anywhere in your network. Running it directly from VS means it's hosted inside VS's ASP.NET Development Server (which, by default is only accessible locally). You can try opening up the port specified in the ASP.NET development server that starts up on your machine's local firewall, then you can access the debug instance being hosted